# implementing a min/max Heap in rust

Tags: rust, heap

I am more on data analyst than a programmer, but I do enjoy coding for fun. I tried to implement a Heap in rust. I would appreciate any return you may have, so I can improve.

````
//! a minimal heap implementation support minimum and maximum heap, insertion,
//! heapify and pop/peeks at the top node.
//! Support optional data attached to a node

#[derive(Debug)]
///
/// T is a numeric value used to sort the heap
/// D is the attached type, if max is true the heap is maximum heap else it is minimum heap
///``` rust
/// let mut my_heap = Heap::new(5,  Some(Box::new("chocolate")), false);
/// ```
pub struct Heap<T, D>{ data: Option<Vec<(T, Option<Box<D>>)>>, max: bool}


impl <T, D> Heap<T, D> where T: PartialEq + Copy + std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::fmt::Debug,
                             D: std::fmt::Debug + Copy, {
    /// create a new non empty heap
    ///``` rust
    /// let mut my_heap = Heap::new(5, Some(Box::new("chocolate")), false);
    ///  // or
    /// let mut my_heap<i32, &str> = Heap::new(5, None, false);
    /// ```
    pub fn new(value: T, data: Option<Box<D>>,
           max: bool) -> Self {


        Heap{data: Some(vec![(value, data)]), max }
    }

    pub fn new_empty(max: bool) -> Self {

        Heap{data: None, max }
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool{
        match &self.data{
            Some(_x) => false,
            _ => true
        }
    }



    /// swap 2 values from the heap
    fn swap(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Result<(), &'static str> {

        if self.is_empty(){
               return Err("can't swap value of an empty heap");
        }

        let heap_size  = self.get_size()?;

        if (heap_size <= x) |  (heap_size <= y){
            return Err("swapping indice are out of index");
        }

        match self.data{
             Some(ref mut data) => {
                 let p = data[x].clone();
                 data[x] = data[y].clone();
                 data[y] = p;
                 return Ok(());
             },
            _ => {return Err("error unwrapping heap while swapping");}
        };

            //let p = self.data[x].clone();
            //self.data[x] = self.data[y].clone();
          //  self.data[y] = p;
        //()
    }

    /// insert a new values in the heap
    ///``` rust
    /// let mut my_heap = Heap::new(5,  Some(Box::new("chocolate")), true);
    ///  result.insert(8, Some(Box::new("beast")));
    ///  result.insert(2, None);
    ///```
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T, data: Option<Box<D>>) -> Result<(), &'static str>{

        if self.is_empty(){
            self.data.as_mut().unwrap().push((value, data));
            return Ok(());
        }

        self.data.as_mut().unwrap().push((value, data));
        let mut current_index = self.get_size()? - 1;
        let mut parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;

        match self.max{
            false => {
                while parent.1 > value{
                    self.swap(current_index, parent.0)?;
                    current_index = parent.0;
                    if current_index != 0{
                    parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;}
                    else{break}
                }
            },
            true => {
                while parent.1 < value{
                    self.swap(current_index, parent.0)?;
                    current_index = parent.0;
                    if current_index != 0{
                    parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;}
                    else{break}
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    /// return a tuple, cloned value T / data D  of the top node.
    pub fn peeks_top(&self) -> Result<(T, Option<Box<D>>), &'static str>{
        if self.is_empty(){
            return Err("can't peeks at an empty heap");
        }
        match &self.data{
            Some(data) => Ok((data[0].0, data[0].1.clone())),
            _ => return Err("unwrapping while peeking")
        }
        //Ok((self.data.unwrap()[0].0, self.data.unwrap()[0].1.clone()))
    }


    fn heapify(&mut self, indice: usize) -> Result<(), &'static str>{

        if self.is_empty(){
            return Err("can't heapify empty Heap");
        }

        let length_heap = self.get_size()?;
        println!("{} {}", indice, length_heap);

        let mut should_be_on_top = indice;

        let l = Self::get_left_child(indice);
        let r = Self::get_right_child(indice);

        match self.max{

            true => {
                if r < length_heap{
                     if  self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[r].0 > self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[should_be_on_top].0{
                        should_be_on_top = r
                    }
                }

                if l < length_heap {
                    if self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[l].0 > self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[should_be_on_top].0 {
                        should_be_on_top = l
                    }
                }
            },
            false => {
                if r < length_heap {
                    if self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[r].0 < self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[should_be_on_top].0{
                    should_be_on_top = r
                    }
                }

                if l < length_heap {
                    if self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[l].0 < self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[should_be_on_top].0{

                    should_be_on_top = l
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if should_be_on_top != indice{
            self.swap(indice, should_be_on_top);
            self.heapify(should_be_on_top);
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_size(&self) -> Result<usize, &'static str>{
        if self.is_empty(){
            return Err("empty Heap has no size");
        }
        Ok(self.data.as_ref().unwrap().len())
    }

    /// remove the top node from the heap, heapify the heap. Finaly, return the tuple (value<T>/data<D>) from the removed top node
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Result<(T, Option<Box<D>>), &'static str>{
        self.swap(0, self.get_size()? - 1)?;

        let popped = self.data.as_mut().unwrap().pop();
        self.heapify(0);
        match popped{
        Some(x) => Ok(x),
        _ => return Err("error unwrapping after pop and heapify")
        }
    }

    fn get_parent(&self, position: usize) -> Result<(usize, T), &'static str>{
        if self.is_empty(){
            return Err("no parent in empty Heap");
        }
        let x = (position - 1) / 2;
        Ok((x, self.data.as_ref().unwrap()[x].0))
    }

    fn get_left_child(indice: usize) -> usize { indice * 2 + 1 }

    fn get_right_child(indice : usize) -> usize{ indice * 2 + 2 }
}
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Formatting

Your current code is hard to read. The indentation of e.g. the trait bounds seems weird to me. Also the indentation and extra newlines in `Heap::new()` seems off to me. You can format your code accoring to the standard code style guidelines using `cargo fmt` or `rustfmt` respectively.

## Unnecessary trait bounds

You require `PartialEq` and `PartialOrd` as trait bounds. But `PartialOrd` [implies `PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html). Therefore, the trait bound `PartialEq` is superfluous.

Furthermore, the trait bound to `Copy` is a rather heavy restriction. Consider relaxing it to `Clone` and call `T.clone()` explicitly where necessary.

## Useless use of `match`

`match self.max {}` seems like overkill. `match` is intended for structural pattern matching. Since `self.max` is a `bool` a plain old `if self.max {} else {}` would suffice.

## API design

You only use `self.max` in `insert()` and `heapify()`. Consider removing it as a struct member and making it a method parameter instead.
This would also allow for `new_empty()` to be replaced by an appropriate implementation of `Default`.

I.e.:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub struct Heap<T, D> {
    data: Option<Vec<(T, Option<Box<D>>)>>,
}

impl<T, D> Heap<T, D>
where
    T: Clone + PartialOrd + Debug,
    D: Clone + Debug,
{
    pub fn new(value: T, data: Option<Box<D>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: Some(vec![(value, data)]),
        }
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.data.is_none()
    }

    // ...

    pub fn insert(
        &mut self,
        value: T,
        data: Option<Box<D>>,
        max: bool,
    ) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        if self.is_empty() {
            self.data.as_mut().unwrap().push((value, data));
            return Ok(());
        }

        self.data.as_mut().unwrap().push((value, data));
        let mut current_index = self.get_size()? - 1;
        let mut parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;

        if max {
            while parent.1 < value {
                self.swap(current_index, parent.0)?;
                current_index = parent.0;
                if current_index != 0 {
                    parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            while parent.1 > value {
                self.swap(current_index, parent.0)?;
                current_index = parent.0;
                if current_index != 0 {
                    parent = self.get_parent(current_index)?;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T, D> Default for Heap<T, D> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { data: None }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your return! It is really helpful. I have a question about the API design paragraph. I do not understand what you mean by “removing it as a struct member and making it a method parameter instead”. I believe (maybe wrongly) that those are method because I defined them in the "impl" of the struct. Could you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for the Edit!

Comment: There is a very good reason to use `max` as a struct member (or generic parameter) though => it guarantees consistency. If `insert` is called half the time with `max = true` and the other half with `max = false`, you create a mess, not a heap.

Answer (score 5):

#### Unusual API

It's unusual for a heap API to be a key/value API, and even more unusual here is the fact that the "value" part is optional, so that some keys will be associated with a value, and others won't.

A more traditional API would be to take one element, and let the user create a struct implementing PartialEq/PartialOrd taking only a subset of fields into account as appropriate to their use-case.

*Note: it's also VERY weird to force the value to be boxed, I'd never use a collection which forces me to allocate for each value.... imagine if I wanted to store a `u8` there???*

#### Why `Option<Vec<...>>`?

What's the difference between `None` and `Some(vec![])`, semantically, for your heap?

It's unlikely there's any, and therefore the `Option<...>` layer around `Vec` is strictly superfluous.

Note that `Vec::new()`, which creates an empty vector, does not allocate. In fact, it's even `const` thanks to not allocating.

#### Min/Max

The Rust standard library provides the [`Reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) type. Wrapping a value in `Reverse` reverses its `<`/`>` operators.

Hence, given a `MaxHeap<T>`, defining a `MinHeap<T>` is essentially just as simple as:

```rust
type MinHeap<T> = MaxHeap<Reverse<T>>;
```

As such, the min/max parameter is somewhat superfluous. The user can already go from min to max or max to min easily enough.

#### Unusual bounds

Idiomatic Rust code tends to avoid bounds on code that doesn't need them.

There's no need for the element to be `PartialOrd` in the `new` method, nor in `is_empty` or `len` or `capacity`, nor in `peek`, ...

It's typical to create several `impl` blocks, with various sets of bounds.

#### Unusual `new`

In the standard library, the `new` method typically creates an empty collection. So should yours.

As a bonus, `new` could then be `const`.

*Note: also consider a `with_capacity` constructor, to allow creating a heap with the right capacity, and avoid consecutive reallocations.*

#### Unusual `get_size`

In the standard library, the number of elements in a collection is returned by the `len` method.

#### Unusual organization

In general, I would advise putting the `pub` items/methods at the top of the file, and the "helper" items/methods towards the bottom.

I would also advise putting the simple methods (`new`, `is_empty`, `len`, `capacity`, `peek`, ...) towards the top, and the more complex methods below, so the user can get a quicker overview of available methods.

#### No documentation

Your public items and methods should have documentation `///`.

Most notably, on collection, I'd want to know:

1. If a method may or may not lead to a memory allocation, and if yes under which circumstances.
2. If a method may panic, under which circumstances it may do so.
3. What is the algorithm complexity in time/space of the call.
4. Possibly, what are related methods, when multiple methods have somewhat similar/opposite goals.
5. Example usage code can be nice, and doubles as test too.

#### No test

Speaking of tests, I don't see any.

For collections, I'd really advise setting up some *fuzzing* tests. For a heap, for example:

- I'd generate a vector of N elements from 0 to N-1.
- I'd randomly shuffle that vector.
- I'd create a new heap, and feed it the vector elements.
- I'd then create a new vector by popping the elements one by one.
- I'd check that the resulting vector is sorted (ascending or descending, accordingly).

#### Iteration

Your code is missing iterator support, which is perhaps the single most important piece to be a useful collection in the Rust ecosystem.

Specifically, you'll want:

- To implement `FromIterator` and `Extend`, so the heap can be constructed/extended from all the elements of an iterator.
- To implement `IntoIterator`, so the heap can be "deconstructed" into an iterator yields its elements.

Those are the basics for a collection.

You may not want to implement just "browsing", though, as there should be no need for a user to peek into the heap internal structure.

#### Revised API

```rust
/// A Max Heap.
///
/// To use as a Min Heap instead, wrap your elements in `std::cmp::Reverse`.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct MaxHeap<T>;

impl<T> MaxHeap<T> {
    /// Creates a new, empty, instance.
    pub const fn new() -> Self;

    /// Creates a new, empty, instance with the capacity for at least the specified
    /// number of elements.
    pub fn with_capacity(cap: usize) -> Self;

    /// Returns whether there is an element in the heap, or not.
    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool;

    /// Returns the number of elements in the heap.
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize;

    /// Returns the number of elements the heap may contain without any reallocation.
    pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize;

    /// Reserves capacity for `additional` more elements.
    ///
    /// After this call, `self.capacity() >= self.len() + additional`.
    ///
    /// This requires a memory allocation if `additional > self.capacity() - self.len()`.
    pub fn reserve(&mut self, additional: usize);

    /// Returns a reference to the top element, if any.
    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T>;
}

impl<T> MaxHeap<T>
where
    T: PartialOrd,
{
    /// Pops the top element of the heap.
    ///
    /// # Algorithmic Complexity
    ///
    /// O(log N) in time, O(1) in space.
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>;

    /// Pushes an element in the heap.
    ///
    /// This requires a memory allocation if `self.len() == self.capacity()`.
    ///
    /// # Algorithmic Complexity
    ///
    /// O(log N) in time, O(1) in space.
    pub fn push(&mut self, element: T);
}

impl<T> Default for MaxHeap<T> {
    fn default() -> Self { Self::new() }
}
```

And `Iterator` compatibility:

```rust
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for MaxHeap<T> {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = T>
    {
        //  -- Semi-naive implementation --
        let iter = iter.into_iter();

        let mut heap = Self::with_capacity(iter.size_hint().0);

        for element in iter {
            heap.push(element);
        }

        heap

        //  -- Optimized implementation --
        let mut heap = Self { data: Vec::from_iter(iter) };

        heap.heapify();

        heap
    }
}

impl<T> Extend<T> for MaxHeap<T> {
    fn extend<I>(&mut self, iter: I)
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = T>
    {
        //  -- Semi-naive implementation --
        let iter = iter.into_iter();

        //  Pre-reserving to avoid allocation in the loop.
        self.reserve(iter.size_hint().0);

        for element in iter {
            heap.push(element);
        }

        //  Not sure what an optimized implementation would look like;
        //  probably differs based on the ratio of existing elements and
        //  number of elements to insert.
    }
}

impl<T> IntoIterator for MaxHeap<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        IntoIter(self)
    }
}

/// An Iterator over the elements of a `MaxHeap<T>`.
pub struct IntoIter<T>(MaxHeap<T>);

impl<T> Iterator for IntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.pop()
    }

    //  The following methods are provided as optimizations over the default
    //  implementations.

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (self.0.len(), Some(self.0.len())
    }

    fn count(self) -> usize {
        self.0.len()
    }
}

impl<T> ExactSizeIterator for IntoIter<T> {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool { self.0.is_empty() }

    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.0.len() }
}

//  A "fused" iterator is an iterator with a "fuse", that is an iterator which will
//  never again return an element after returning `None`.
impl<T> FusedIterator for IntoIter<T> {}
```

You may additionally provide a simple `KeyValue` helper:

```rust
/// A simple key value pair.
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct KeyValue<K, V> {
    /// Key, on which the identity and ordering is based.
    pub key: K,
    /// Value, which does not participate to identity or ordering.
    pub value: V,
}

impl<K, V> PartialEq for KeyValue<K, V>
where
    K: PartialEq,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool { self.key.eq(&other.key) }
}

impl<K, V> PartialOrd for KeyValue<K, V>
where
    K: PartialOrd,
{
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        self.key.partial_cmp(&other.key)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the extensive review, there is a lot to chew for me and it is definitely very helpful!